# Why array.prototype.map.call(..) doesn't work in case prototype framework using there?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, prototypejs, prototype

If I use this code without prototype framework:

```
if (XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary) return;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.sendAsBinary = function(datastr) {
            function byteValue(x) {
                return x.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
            }
            console.log(Array.prototype.map);
            var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr, byteValue);
            var ui8a = new Uint8Array(ords);
            this.send(ui8a.buffer);
        }
```

log returns:

```
function map() { [native code] }
```

If prototype js framework included then log returns this one:

```
function collect(iterator, context) {
    iterator = iterator || Prototype.K;
    var results = [];
    this.each(function(value, index) {
      results.push(iterator.call(context, value, index));
    });
    return results;
  }
```

At the same time I got an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object String] has no method 'each' prototype.js:864
collect prototype.js:864
XMLHttpRequest.sendAsBinary jquery.filedrop.js:309
send jquery.filedrop.js:215
```

jQuery is using also anyway.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Why I cannot run native map function in case prototype framework is on?

Comment: is `datastr` an array? (the answer is no.) prototype overrides `Array.prototype.map` with it's own method. said method appears to not work on strings.

Comment: I guess you could "fix" it by making the string an array, `datastr.split("")`, at that point you can simply do `var ords = datastr.split("").map(byteValue)`

Comment: datastr is a image string data.

Comment: var ords = datastr.split("").map(byteValue) seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you include prototypejs, `Array.prototype.map` is replaced with a prototypejs method. The new method assumes it will always be called on an array, which causes your usecase to fail since you're calling it on a string.

A workaround is to convert your string to an array.

```
var ords = Array.prototype.map.call(datastr.splt(""), byteValue);
```

which can then be simplified to:

```
var ords = datastr.splt("").map(byteValue);
```